# Updating a GUI with ComboBox using GUIKit

Tags: gui-construction

Dear Mathematica users,

does anyone know how I can update my existing Gui window (made with GUIKit) by choosing different values of a ComboBox so that different and multiple TextFields etc appear depending on the current value of the ComboBox. The created TextFields should appear in the same window below the ComboBox and they should update once the value of the ComboBox is changed.

I appreciate any help

this is what I've tried so far

```
Widget["Frame",
 {Widget["ComboBox", {
"items" -> Script[{"Choice A", "Choice B", "Choice C",  "Choice D",  
   "Choice E"}], BindEvent["action", Script[updateSource[]]]}, Name -> "comboSource"] ,

Widget["Panel", list],

Widget["Label", {"text" -> "Distance from the source[m]"}], 
Widget["TextField", {"text" -> "0"}, Name -> "SourceTextField0"],
Widget["Label", {"text" -> "Sourcesize"}], 
Widget["TextField", {"text" -> "0"}, Name -> "SourceTextField1"],
Widget["Label", {"text" -> "b: "}], 
Widget["TextField", {"text" -> "1"}, Name -> "SourceTextField2"],
Widget["Label", {"text" -> "c: "}], 
Widget["TextField", {"text" -> "2"}, Name -> "SourceTextField3"],
Widget["Label", {"text" -> "d: "}], 
Widget["TextField", {"text" -> "3"}, Name -> "SourceTextField4"],
Widget["Button", {"text" -> "Done", 
BindEvent["action", 
 Script[InvokeMethod[{"FrameSource", "dispose"}]]]}],
Script[updateSource[] := Block[{}, list = widglist]; list = {}], 
"title" -> "Source"}, Name -> "FrameSource" ]
```

My hope was, that using a function called **updateSource[]** I can use **Widget["Panel",list]** and display a list where some predefined widgets are stored. Unfortunately, this doesn't work because Mathematica returns an error

```
Widget::deferr: Widget[Panel,list] is not valid GUI definition content. >>
GUIRun::nvalid: The GUI definition contains invalid content. >>
```

Is there a clever way of solving my problem?

Dennis

Comment: Dear Dennis, welcome to Mathematica.SE! It would help if you posted code showing what you have tried.